# google maps API v3 events

Tags: google-maps-api-3, maps

I have the following situation:

A polyline is added on the map and when the user clicks over it its state changes to editable. Also i have event where if the user clicks the last vertext of the polyline and starts moving the mouse to be able to extend the polyline with the mouse path the user is drawing.

However it seems that when i have an event and inside this event i try to add another one it simply does not work and i don't kwow why.

Just in case to make things simpler to undrstand i will paste a part of my code.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(polyLine, "mousedown", function(event){
               if(polyLine.getEditable() === true) 
               {
                   if(typeof event.vertex !== "undefined") 
                   {    
                        if(event.vertex === polyLine.getPath().getLength() - 1) 
                        {
                            polyLine.setEditable(false);

                                if(mouseMoveDrawingEvent === null)
                                {
                                    map.setOptions({draggable:false});
                                    polyLine.setOptions({clickable:false});
                                    mouseMoveDrawingEvent = google.maps.event.addListener(map, "mousemove", function(event) 
                                    {
                                        alert("1"); // <== this never fires
                                        polyLine.getPath().push(event.latLng);
                                        drawingLabel.setPoint(event.latLng);
                                        drawingLabel.setContents("<div style='background-color:white'>" + (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeLength(polyLine.getPath()) / 1000).toFixed(2) + " км.</div>");
                                    });
                                }    

                            map.getDiv().onmouseup = function(ev) {
                                polyLine.setOptions({clickable:true});
                                map.getDiv().onmousedown = null;
                                map.getDiv().onmouseup = null;
                                google.maps.event.removeListener(mouseMoveDrawingEvent);
                                mouseMoveDrawingEvent = null;
                            };
                        }
                   }
               }
           });
```

.....

thre is another event here that listens for 'mouseup'....

Do you guys have any idea how to make this peace of code works.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my questions.

The problem was that when i set the polyline {clickable:false} the api removes the event ( and obviously everyhing inside it:)